# Vaadin Best approach: distribute object state changes to other components

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, vaadin

I'm dealing with a WebApp (Vaadin19) and stuck now in the question, how to share an object-state change from one component to another. There is one object instance in two or more components. After changing an attribute of the object in one component and going back to another component, I want to see the changed attribute.

Let me explain, what I mean:

1. There is a grid with some lines of data. The grid shows only a subset of the data to respect the clarity.
2. A click on the grid opens a detailed view in "read mode". The data is structured (contains sub-objects itself).
3. A click on the "read mode"-view opens then a dialog with tabs. The activated tab depends on the sub-object, that was clicked before.

After changing an element in the sub-object and closing the dialog, I want that the UI will reload/revalidate it's content. I think it's clear, that I use there the same object-instance.

Is there an event I have to submit to the UI?

Or:
What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

The actual refresh is easy: `theGrid.getDataProvider().refreshAll()`, or `refreshItem` instead if you have access to the item that has been changed and it has a good implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`.

How to hook things up so that the dialog notifies the grid is then really depending on your architecture.

- If they are already close to each other in the code, then you could e.g. store a reference to the Grid in an instance field and just reference that in the dialog handler.
- If you want to decouple, then you need some kind of event bus. You can use the regular Spring event mechanisms as long as you ensure that the event stays within the UI scope. Alternatively, you can use `ComponentUtil::addListener` and `ComponentUtil::fireEvent` to use e.g. `UI.getCurrent` as a simple event bus.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think in my situation would be the listener solution the right tech for me.